# Is there a way to go beyond the tipped arrow limitations?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a certain command to get some arrow such as maybe instant health 3 or more?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, using NBT tags! Specifically, the tag `CustomPotionEffects`.
It takes three identifiers, id (which is the effect given), duration (in seconds), and amplifier (strength of the effect).

You can use a generator such as [this one](https://www.gamergeeks.net/apps/minecraft/give-command-generator/potions) to make potions or tipped arrows for you, but I've explained how they work fully below.

Here's an example of an instant health 3 arrow.

```
/give @p minecraft:tipped_arrow{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:6,Duration:0,Amplifier:2}],display:{Name:'[{"text":"Instant Health III Arrow"}]'}} 64
```

I'll break it down in more detail.

`Id:6` is the numerical ID of the effect. Unlike block IDs, effect IDs use numbers to represent each value inside NBT, making it more difficult, so you can consult [this list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Effect) to find the one you want.
`Duration:0` is the duration, in seconds. This tag is actually optional, and any value below/equal to 0 will be treated as 1. It caps at 2147483647 (the 32-bit integer limit).
`Amplifier:2` is the level of the effect minus one; think of amplifiers as adding onto the default effect level of 1. This caps at 255, for a maximum effect level of 256.

For more information on the possible NBT values of `CustomPotionEffects`, you can see the minecraft wiki page [here.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Potion_Effects)

Note that **all potions or arrows given like this will be pink**, as they are otherwise unobtainable. You can change the colour with a different tag, `CustomPotionColor`, e.g a red regeneration 1 effect lasting 90 seconds would be:

```
/give @p tipped_arrow{CustomPotionColor:16711680,CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:10,Duration:90,Amplifier:0}],display:{Name:'[{"text":"Regen 1 Arrow"}]'}} 64
```

You'll definitely need to use the [generator](https://www.gamergeeks.net/apps/minecraft/give-command-generator/potions) to find exactly the colour you want.